# Two rows having same color in SQL Server reporting

Tags: c#, reporting-services, report, sql-server-data-tools, rdl

The project is using SQL Server reports with N number of rows on it. My requirement was having a background color of a row in an alternative way.

To achieve this following expression were provided to `backgroundcolor` property of rows:

```
=IIf(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 1, "RED", "BLUE")
```

Everything works perfectly, except the second and third line of a second page having the same color:

[image]

Considering the following properties of report:

- Grouping applied on first column of a report. However, entries of
  first row can be repeated.
- Not a single column having unique entry hence grouping on any column
  giving the same issue.

In nutshell, is it possible to give an alternative background color to row where grouping was applied and repeated entries where skiped?

Comment: Do you have a `Visibility` filter on the table rows?

Comment: @iamdave. Thanks for a quick reply. Yes, under visibility "Hidden" property set to false for all rows.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your report Design View to your answer?  You haven't really given us much to work with in helping you with this issue...

Comment: Is there any row grouping going on? Please edit your question to show this too.

Comment: Yes. There is a grouping. Thanks for the suggestion. will update the question accordingly.

Comment: @iamdave updated question with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience concerning your particular issue (so apologies in advance if it this doesn't work); but the way I've done this in regular reports is to have a hidden column using an expression. In your case you would have to put this expression **inside your row group** as a hidden column:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!Code.Value, countDistinct, Nothing)
```

RunningValue is similar to an identity column in SQL Server, where every new row increments the value +1.

You should rename this hidden cell to something meaningful like ROWCOLOR.  If you right-click the cell and select Text Box Properties- set the Name to ROWCOLOR.

The background color for the rows is alternated using another expression such as:

```
=IIF(VAL(ReportItems!ROWCOLOR.Value) MOD 2, "RED", "BLUE")
```